# Finale: How do I add note to an existing chord using the simple entry tool?

Tags: notation

The title is pretty self-explanatory.  I have an existing chord of one or more notes.  I'm in simple entry mode.  I can use the left/right arrow keys to move between chords.  But the up/down arrows move the existing note rather than allowing me to add a new note to the chord.

Comment: Should have asked this over at http://audio.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @IanC: Yep, except that site didn't exist until 2 months after I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - Use the numbers to add an interval.  For example, `3` to add a note a 3rd above the selected note, `4` to add a 4th, and use `Shift` to add the new note below the selected note instead of above.